# Actionscript 3 (flash game) with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to embed a flash game in a node app. I think I have set up the sockets correctly - I am not receiving any errors - but when I go to the page where the game is supposed to load, I just see a blank white screen where the flash game should be - and when I right-click on the screen it says something like, "Movie not loaded." Seeing as I don't see any errors, I'm not sure where to begin. Here is my code:

AvoiderGame.as

```
package {

// --------------------------------------
// Imports
// --------------------------------------
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.DataEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

// --------------------------------------
// Class
// --------------------------------------

    public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var enemy:Enemy;
        public var avatar:Avatar;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        private var _xmlSocket:XMLSocket;        

        public function AvoiderGame() 
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild( enemy );

            avatar = new Avatar();
            addChild( avatar );
            avatar.x = mouseX;
            avatar.y = mouseY;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);

            gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
            gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
            gameTimer.start();
        }

        public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
        {
            enemy.moveDownABit();
            avatar.x = mouseX;
            avatar.y = mouseY;

            if ( avatar.hitTestObject( enemy ) ) 
            {
                gameTimer.stop();
            }
        }

        function doConnect(evt:MouseEvent):void  
        {  
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);  
            _xmlSocket = new XMLSocket("127.0.0.1", 9000);    
            _xmlSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);  
            _xmlSocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);  
        }

        function onConnect(evt:Event):void  
        {  
            trace("Connected");  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);  

            _xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);  
            _xmlSocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, on_xmlSocketClose);              
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);  
        }  

        function onError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void  
        {  
            trace("Connect failed");  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);  
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);  
        }

        function keyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void  
        {  
            if (evt.keyCode == 81) // the key code for q is 81  
            {  
                _xmlSocket.send("exit");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                _xmlSocket.send(evt.keyCode);  
            }  
        }

        function onDataReceived(evt:DataEvent):void  
        {  
            try {  
                trace("From Server:",  evt.data );  
            }  
            catch (e:Error) {  
                trace('error');  
            }  
        }  

        function on_xmlSocketClose(evt:Event):void  
        {  
            trace("Connection Closed");  
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, on_xmlSocketClose);  
            _xmlSocket.removeEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);  
        }     
    }
}
```

server.js (node server file):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

/**
 * Main application file
 */

// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var config = require('./lib/config/config');
var db = mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

// Bootstrap models
var modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib/models');
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  if (/(.*)\.(js$|coffee$)/.test(file)) {
    require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
  }
});

// Populate empty DB with sample data
//require('./lib/config/dummydata');

// Passport Configuration
var passport = require('./lib/config/passport');

// Setup Express
var app = express();
require('./lib/config/express')(app);
require('./lib/routes')(app);

var server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Start server
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %s:%d, in %s mode', config.ip, config.port, app.get('env'));
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

game.html (partial where game is loaded - I am using angular for front-end):

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar.html'"></div>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>

<div class="jumbotronpage">
    <div id="flashContent">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="400" height="300" id="avoider" align="middle">
        <param name="movie" value="avoider.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/home/yz/webdev/angfull/oneclick/avoider.swf" width="400" height="300">
            <param name="movie" value="avoider.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>
</div>
```

I basically took the `flashContent` div straight out of what Adobe Flash CC published as an HTML wrapper for the game (it works if I just locally run the file without going through the server from the published html wrapper file). If you notice anything let me know. Again - my problem is that the flash game doesn't load (just a white screen) - I'm not receiving any errors that I can see. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Updated code to reflect how I am using it with socket.io. Adding script on index.html to show client side socket.io connection.

index.html (script for client-side):

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it seems that your _swf_ file wasn't loaded because of wrong path. Try absolute path instead of _partials/avoider.swf_ or look in the browser devtool for the loading errors.

Comment: @fsbmain thanks! I usually am looking at the dev console but I didn't see any errors...where do I see loading errors so I can examine the path?

Comment: on the _network_ tab (ff or chrome)

Comment: @fsbmain thanks, I clicked on the network tab - looks like all the pages get loaded successfully - how do I see where it is messing up with the flash game?

Comment: @fsbmain I made the <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="partials/avoider.swf" width="400" height="300"> line this: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="absolute path to/avoider.swf" width="400" height="300"> and it is still blank

Comment: @fsbmain I was using chrome and didn't see it - but when I open up firefox I see it now - but it says "304 Not Modified" so after changing to absolute path I think it is loading...but it is still a blank screen - I am on linux and using chrome because flash and chrome like eachother much more than flash and firefox (iceweasel is what I'm using).

Comment: @fsbmain - i realized some of the code is wrong for socket.io - im going to update the files to reflect my changes.

Comment: @fsbmain the problem isnt solved - just realized some other mistakes I had.

Comment: @fsbmain I'm dling flash builder and im gonna try to use flashsocket.io

Comment: @fsbmain https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO - can you explain the part where it says: "Because this library is dependent on the websocket library, you must add the support/websocket-js path to you source path in flash builder or your build files."

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to use flash sockets and websockets simultaneously with socket io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527249/is-it-possible-to-use-flash-sockets-and-websockets-simultaneously-with-socket-io)